# AngularJS [typeahead] reopen result dropdown on onFocus

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, typeahead, angular-ui-typeahead

I have problem in following use case in **typeahead**:

## Problem:

- user starts typing, dropdown opens and shows results
- user clicks out of the input field (nothing is deleted from the input field), dropdown closes
- user clicks back into the typeahead input field (and does NOT start to type anything) and nothing happens. → the desired behavior is: dropdown opens again and shows the same result list as last time (of course, that only happens, if there is anything in the input field)
- When user search anything and if result found and focus lost occurs and string does not get cleared again focus nothing happen, no hints
- When user seach anything and if result not found and focus lost occurs string get cleared and there is also message of no data found.

**So, Moral of the story is that in first case string should get cleared if it is not selected from list and it is substring of list string...**

So, maybe a typeahead-search-on-focus setting?

## HTML:

```
<input type="text" focus-me="opened" ng-focus="onFocus($event)" ng-show="opened" ng-trim="false" ng-model="selected" empty-typeahead typeahead="state for state in states | filter:$viewValue:stateComparator" class="form-control" />
```

## JS:

```
(function () {
var secretEmptyKey = '[$empty$]'

angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap'])
.directive('focusMe', function($timeout, $parse) {
  return {
      //scope: true,   // optionally create a child scope
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          var model = $parse(attrs.focusMe);
          scope.$watch(model, function(value) {
              if(value === true) { 
                  $timeout(function() {
                      element[0].focus();
                  });
              }
          });
      }
  };
})
.directive('emptyTypeahead', function () {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
      // this parser run before typeahead's parser
      modelCtrl.$parsers.unshift(function (inputValue) {
        var value = (inputValue ? inputValue : secretEmptyKey); // replace empty string with secretEmptyKey to bypass typeahead-min-length check
        modelCtrl.$viewValue = value; // this $viewValue must match the inputValue pass to typehead directive
        return value;
      });
      
      // this parser run after typeahead's parser
      modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (inputValue) {
        return inputValue === secretEmptyKey ? '' : inputValue; // set the secretEmptyKey back to empty string
      });
    }
  }
})
.controller('TypeaheadCtrl', function($scope, $http, $timeout) {
  $scope.selected = undefined;
  $scope.states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Wyoming'];
  $scope.opened = true;
  
  $scope.stateComparator = function (state, viewValue) {
    return viewValue === secretEmptyKey || (''+state).toLowerCase().indexOf((''+viewValue).toLowerCase()) > -1;
  };
  
  $scope.onFocus = function (e) {
    $timeout(function () {
      $(e.target).trigger('input');
      $(e.target).trigger('change'); // for IE
    });
  };
});
}());
```

I have this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Qrnat8yTvISuM1qHHDlA?p=preview) to show how my code looks like.

There is also [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/6046).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Hello Everyone,

After some efforts i got the proper solution...

There are some directives that can be useful for the solution,

**Add above condition in `typeaheadFocus` directive,**

```
    if ((e.type == "focus" && viewValue != ' ') && (e.type == "focus" && viewValue != '')){
        return;
    }
```

**Add following function in `typeaheadFocus` directive and `typeaheadOnDownArrow` directive,**

```
    //compare function that treats the empty space as a match
    scope.$emptyOrView = function(actual) {
        if(ngModel.$viewValue.trim()) {
            return actual ? actual.value.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(ngModel.$viewValue.toLowerCase()) > -1 : false;
        }
        return true;
    };
```

**Change this condition in ui-bootstrap.js,**

```
  if (inputFormatter) {
     locals.$model = modelValue;
     if(modelValue){
     locals.$label = view_value;
  } else {
     locals.$label = '';
  }
```

**Add following `event` in ui-bootstrap js,**

```
element.bind('blur', function(evt) {
   hasFocus = false;
   if (!isEditable && modelCtrl.$error.editable) {
      element.val('');
      modelCtrl.$viewValue = ' ';
   }
   if(!isEditable && scope.no_data_found) {
         //ngModel.$viewValue = '';
         modelCtrl.$viewValue = ' ';
         scope.no_data_found = false;
         popUpEl.find('.typeaheadNoData').remove();
         resetMatches();
         scope.$digest();
         element.val("");
   }
});
```

**Add this in ui-bootstrap.js,**

```
        // I listen for emptyTypeAhead events from the parent scope chain.
    originalScope.$on(
        "emptyTypeAhead",
        function handlePingEvent( event, newVal1) {
            var scope = originalScope.$new();
            modelCtrl.$setViewValue(newVal1);
            return newVal1;
        }
    );
```

**Add the above function with ui-bootstrap.js in all directive,**

```
.directive('shouldFocus', function($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.shouldFocus, function(newVal, oldVal) {
                var isActive = scope.$eval(attrs.shouldFocus);
                if(isActive) {
                    var ele = element[0];
                    var parent = ele.parentNode

                    if(ele.offsetTop + ele.offsetHeight > parent.offsetHeight + parent.scrollTop){
                        parent.scrollTop = ele.offsetTop;
                    } else if(parent.scrollTop > ele.offsetTop) {
                        parent.scrollTop = ele.offsetTop;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

## Example:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="inquiry.account" 
 placeholder="Select Account" 
 typeahead="account.id as account.text for account in account_typeahead_json" 
 typeahead-input-formatter="formatModel($model,$label)" 
 typeahead-editable="false" typeahead-on-down-arrow typeahead-focus />
```

Hope this answer will be helpful for you.

## [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/lWDgOExJZCKIuYOSdbzu) I have added `ui-bootstrap.js`